# ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.6

I wrote a unit test to update a record and when i try to run my test, it passes sometimes and fails at other times with the error

> ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
>   I have no idea why this is happening. Checked other post with similar title but nothing related to my case.

Here's the test

```
public function testUpdateBookRecord()
{
    // Select an existing user randomly & authenticate the user.
    $user = User::all()->random();
    Passport::actingAs($user);

    // Get any book belonging to the user.
    $selectedBook = Book::where('user_id', $user->id)->inRandomOrder()->first();

    // Update the book.
    $response = $this->json('PUT', '/api/books/'.$selectedBook->id, [
        'title'     => $this->faker->sentence(),
        'author'    => $this->faker->name()
    ]);

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

And this is the controller responsible for the update

```
public function update(Request $request, Book $book)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title'     => 'required|unique:books',
        'author'    => 'required'
    ]);

    // Update book if the logged in user_id is the same as the book user_id
    if ($request->user()->id === $book->user_id) {
        $book->update($request->only(['title', 'author']));

        return new BookResource($book);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'You do not have the permission for this operation'], 403);
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is it possible that sometimes you don't have any users in your database?

Comment: or here `$selectedBook->id`. so what exactly is the line number of the exception.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan This is the line with the error `$selectedBook = Book::where('user_id', $user->id)->inRandomOrder()->first();`

Comment: @Mena I'm pretty sure `User::all()` returns zero length collection.

Comment: @Jerodev the line throwing the error `$selectedBook = Book::where('user_id', $user->id)->inRandomOrder()->first();` is suppose to check that the user actually has a book

Comment: @krisanalfa no it actually returns a user and I can see it from `dd($user)`

Comment: Can you show me the result of `dd($user)`?

Comment: @krisanalfa ` #original: array:7 [
    "id" => 9
    "name" => "Mariana Padberg II"
    "email" => "larmstrong@example.net"
    "password" => "$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm"
    "remember_token" => "JuDOjjq9Dh"
    "created_at" => "2018-10-05 06:01:21"
    "updated_at" => "2018-10-05 06:01:21"
  ]
`

Comment: It's an array. So, you might access it using `$user['id']` instead of `$user->id`

Comment: show us what does it give `print_r($user)`

Comment: can you try $request->user->id

Answer (score 1):

you can write

```
User::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

or like a comment

```
$user['id'] instead of $user->id
```